# CancellationToken.Register as a mechanism for the event notification vs standard .NET event pattern

Tags: c#, events

In `C#`, despite the original idea of [the new cancellation framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads#operation-cancellation-versus-object-cancellation) to use `CancellationToken.Register` for the purpose of notification to cancel an operation, it could be used just as a mechanism for the simple event notification as well.

Let's take as an example of [`IApplicationLifetime`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs) and its implementation in [ASP.NET/Hosting](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting).

The stripped-down version of [`ApplicationLifetime`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/Internal/ApplicationLifetime.cs) looks like below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows consumers to perform cleanup during a graceful shutdown.
/// </summary>
public class ApplicationLifetime : IApplicationLifetime
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _startedSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host has fully started and is about to wait
    /// for a graceful shutdown.
    /// </summary>
    public CancellationToken ApplicationStarted => _startedSource.Token;

    /// <summary>
    /// Signals the ApplicationStarted event and blocks until it completes.
    /// </summary>
    public void NotifyStarted()
    {
        _startedSource.Cancel(throwOnFirstException: false);
    }
}
```

Client could register for an application startup notification and do something, not necessarily an operation cancellation.

```
lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");
});
```

And then the requesting object could fire a notification:

```
_applicationLifetime?.NotifyStarted();
```

Basically, using the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern) or [updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/modern-events) .NET event pattern you can achieve pretty much the same. Or, do I miss something?

What is the difference from an architecture point of view between these two approaches? Pros and cons? When to use one or another?

Is `CancellationToken.Register` as a mechanism for the simple event notification just a "creative" usage of pattern?

Answer (score 2):

The intention of cancellation tokens is to help with failure states within multi-threaded code. There are built-in methods relating to Tasks that use the cancellation mechanism and so you if you use the same approach you can get your code working seamlessly with them. Having a standard approach makes it easier to write library code as it can assume the caller is using the same approach.

The standard .NET event mechanism has no knowledge of threads and so you would need to handle possible multi-threading issues if it is a potential problem. In simple situations the .NET even mechanism will work just fine. If your own scenario because more complex then you should consider using the cancellation token approach.